# Rect in pygame appears to be there but not blitting

Tags: python, pygame

I got pygame recently and am having problems with blitting a certain rect.
The program itself is an (not finished) undertale battle. When I run the program and press FIGHT (entering FIGHT mode), I should be getting the attackBarRect with the attackLineRect on top of it moving to the left, but it does not show up. However, the FIGHT mode is exited after some time, so the rect is there, but does not show up. I researched on problems blitting a rect but only found topics with error messages (I don't have any) and the fact that the backround is blitted over the item (Tested for that did not work). Please help me.
Full Code:

```
import sys, pygame, time, os
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600,448
menu1=[0,1,0,0]
enemyHealth=3000
attackNumber=0
attackPowerSelf=0
attackPower=1
attackLineX=546
attackLineY=246
def pingdef():
    pass
def menuSelect():
    was=1
    rerun=False
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    x=menu1.index(1)
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]!=0:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if x==3:
            menu1[x]=0
            menu1[0]=1
        else:
            menu1[x]=0
            menu1[x+1]=1
    elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]!=0:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if x==0:
            menu1[x]=0
            menu1[3]=1
        else:
            menu1[x]=0
            menu1[x-1]=1
    elif pressed[pygame.K_z]!=0:
        return x
    else:
        rerun=True
    x=menu1.index(1)
    if x==0:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        if x!=was:
            pingdef()
        screen.blit(fight,fightRect)
        was=x
    if x==1:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        if x!=was:
            pingdef()
        screen.blit(act,actRect)
        was=x
    if x==2:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        if x!=was:
            pingdef()
        screen.blit(item,itemRect)
        was=x
    if x==3:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        if x!=was:
            pingdef()
        screen.blit(mercy,mercyRect)
        was=x
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.display.flip()
    if rerun==True:
        return None
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

backround = pygame.image.load("images\\backround.png")
backroundRect = backround.get_rect()
fight=pygame.image.load("images\\fightSelected.png")
fightRect = fight.get_rect()
act=pygame.image.load("images\\act.png")
actRect = act.get_rect()
item=pygame.image.load("images\\item.png")
itemRect = item.get_rect()
mercy=pygame.image.load("images\\mercy.png")
mercyRect = mercy.get_rect()
attackBar=pygame.image.load("images\\attackBar.png")
attackBarRect = attackBar.get_rect()
attackLine=pygame.image.load("images\\attackLine.png")
attackLineRect = attackLine.get_rect()
pygame.mixer.music.load("sounds\\Megalovenia.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0.0)
screen.blit(fight,fightRect)
screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
pygame.display.flip()
fightRect=fightRect.move(42,403)
actRect=actRect.move(179,403)
itemRect=itemRect.move(324,403)
mercyRect=mercyRect.move(463,403)
attackBarRect=attackBarRect.move(47,246)
attackLineRect=attackLineRect.move(attackLineX,attackLineY)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
    while True:
        selected=menuSelect()
        if selected!=None:
            break
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if selected==0:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        screen.blit(attackBar,attackBarRect)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while True:
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_RETURN]==1 or attackLineRect.left<47:
                attackLineRect=attackLineRect.move(546,246)
                break
            if attackLineRect.right<304:
                attackPowerSelf+=attackPower
            else:
                attackPowerSelf-=attackPower
            attackLineX-=1
            attackLineRect=attackLineRect.move(attackLineX,attackLineY)
            screen.blit(attackBar,attackBarRect)
            screen.blit(attackLine,attackLineRect)
            pygame.event.pump()
            pygame.display.flip()
    if selected==1:
        print("ACT")
    if selected==2:
        print("ITEM")
    if selected==3:
        print("MERCY")
    pygame.display.flip()


wait=input("")
```

Not working part:

```
    if selected==0:
        screen.blit(backround, backroundRect)
        screen.blit(attackBar,attackBarRect)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while True:
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_RETURN]==1 or attackLineRect.left<47:
                attackLineRect=attackLineRect.move(546,246)
                break
            if attackLineRect.right<304:
                attackPowerSelf+=attackPower
            else:
                attackPowerSelf-=attackPower
            attackLineX-=1
            attackLineRect=attackLineRect.move(attackLineX,attackLineY)
            screen.blit(attackBar,attackBarRect)
            screen.blit(attackLine,attackLineRect)
            pygame.event.pump()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're moving the `attackLineRect` downwards and to the right with big steps.

```
attackLineX = 546
attackLineY = 246

# This moves the rect to the right by 546 pixels and down by 246 px.
attackLineRect = attackLineRect.move(attackLineX, attackLineY)
```

Try to print the `attackLineRect` and you'll see that it leaves the screen very quickly.

Change it to, for example, `move(-1, 0)` to move it slowly to the left.

```
attackLineRect = attackLineRect.move(-1, 0)
```

---

Also, your program is structured in a strange way and I'd recommend to post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame) or [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/) to get some tips. But the code should work correctly, so fix the issues first and post the complete code with the images.

One thing you should already use is a `pygame.time.Clock` to limit the frame rate, e.g.:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    # In each while loop call `clock.tick(30)` to limit the frame rate to 30 fps.
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Really helped. Though about the pictures, it might be copyright infringement if I put them here (They are almost the same as the original). Here is my now working code:                     
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju9mwgz9t7wii5u/underthetale.py?dl=0

Comment: Then you could, for example, replace the images with `pygame.Surface`s filled with a color (just for the code review). Alternatively, you can pick some free open source graphics from http://opengameart.org/

Comment: Something else that you can fix pretty quickly: Images should usually be converted after they get loaded, e.g.: `act = pygame.image.load("images\\act.png").convert()` or if it has transparency `act = pygame.image.load("images\\act.png").convert_alpha()`. That will help to improve the performance.